# Force a minimum value in a color ramp classes in QGIS 3.4.1

Tags: qgis, symbology, color-ramp

I am trying to apply a color ramp to a shape using percentage values where red would be low and green would be high.  The data ranges from 74% to 100%, but I need the minimum value to be 0%, so that 74% would actually display as light green.  It currently shows as red because it is the lowest value in the class.

I have other indicators to plot on the same map and want to use the same color ramp, where the lowest value will be much lower than 74%, and I need the color ramp to be consistent across maps.  Such that red is always in the 0 end of the values.

I know I can manually change the values in the classes, but I am hoping there's a more automated way to do this.

I'm using QGIS 3.4.1

Comment: Is this possible in ArcMap? I don't see a + sign in my symbology.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158139)

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility to manually add a new category (it work as well in Categorized or Graduated symbology) by clicking on the '+' sign right to the 'classify' button, so you just have to add a 0 class to shift your color ramp from 74-100 to 0-100

[image]

setting a 5 classes equal interval classification then clicking the "+" then choose a red to green color ramp give you 6 classes, 0 being red, then 74-79 orange and the last green, if you want a true graduation you have to set more classes (in the exemple below I get to a total of 20 classes to simulate classe of around 5%)

You have to choose/attribute the color ramp after adding the 0 classes

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't shift the color map.  I end up with two red classes.

Comment: You have to choose/attribute the color ramp after adding the 0 class. just attribute the same color ramp and it should work

Comment: Just tried that.  Now 0 - 74% is just one red class, and then the next class is 74-79% at orange.  If I apply equal intervals, then it just removes the 0 class again.

Comment: setting a 5 classes equal interval classification then clicking the "+" then choose a red to green color ramp work  for me. give more detail if that's not working for you

Comment: This is what I'm doing:
* Select Graduated Symbols
* Select Column Indicator (contains 162 values between 74% - 100%)
* Class set to 5
* Click + sign (now its 6 classes)
* Select color ramp

Now the color ramp is distributed as follows:
* Red: 0 - 0 
* Orange: 0.74 - 0.79
* Yellow: 0.792 - 0.844
* etc

Comment: I can't seem to embed a picture.  I used to know how...

Comment: see my edited answer for more detail

Comment: Ah, your 2 pictures just loaded above.  You have the same issue as me with the 0-0 then a big jump to .74.

Comment: I want it to automatically classify 0-.20, 26-50, 51-75, 76-100 for me.

Comment: you can't, but you can set 4 classes and by doubleclicking on each class manually edit the value to 0-.20, 26-50, 51-75, 76-100 (for 4 classes it's really not  long to do....)

Comment: No, not long to do.  I just thought there might be an easier way.