# Giving the same color to different shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, color

I have two shapefile consist of many dots. [image] First shapefile's dot values are between -19.060 and 9.680, second shapefile's dot values are between -13.153 and 11.758.
[image]
[image]

I want to apply **the same color ramp** to shapefiles. I want the values of the two shapefiles to appear on the same scale. For example, -10 should be the same color for both layers. I had many attempts at how to do this, but I was not successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to classify a first shapefile with the whole range, in your case from around -20 to 12. You can do this by adding classe with the "+" button next to the classify button and adjusting the classes value by doubleclicking on each class (you will get empty classe, you may want to add a count of point by classes). When the first shapefile is done you just copy the style and paste it to the second shapefile (right click on layer>style>Copy style...)

Also [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/308056/force-a-minimum-value-in-a-color-ramp-classes-in-qgis-3-4-1/308058#308058) could clarify my answer

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the style you want to one layer.

Then right click on the layer in the layers panel. Choose:

`Styles>Copy Style>All Style Categories`

Then right click on the next layer that you want to have the same style. Choose:

`Styles>Paste Style>All Style Categories`

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution to my problem.